# Xcode 5.1.1 - Project Does Not Run in iOS Simulator (Blackscreen)

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, unrecognized-selector

This is my first post!  :D

I started a new Xcode project yesterday for a text based game for the iPhone.  I just started using Objective-C around March, and I took a large break for awhile.  I have a GUI for the storyboard that  shows the narrating text and then four buttons below with options next to them.

After writing a few bits of code for different scenarios, I tried to run the app on the iOS Simulator.  When I tried to run it, only a black screen comes up, with nothing else.

Here is my ViewController.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

// 1 - Initializing the view controller
@interface BKViewController : UIViewController
@property int sit;

// 2 - The narrarator text
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *narText;

// 3 - Buttons
- (IBAction)buttonAPressed:(UIButton *)sender;
- (IBAction)buttonBPressed:(UIButton *)sender;
- (IBAction)buttonCPressed:(UIButton *)sender;
- (IBAction)buttonDPressed:(UIButton *)sender;

// 4 - Option labels
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *optionA;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *optionB;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *optionC;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *optionD;

@end
```

Here is my ViewController.m file:

```
@interface BKViewController ()

@end

@implementation BKViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //Starting attributes
    _sit = 0;

    while (_sit == 0) {
        self.narText.text = @"Welcome to Adventure Game!  Choose an option by tapping a blue button!";
    self.optionA.text = @"What is this?";
    self.optionB.text = @"Let's get started!";
    self.optionC.text = @"What's next?";
    self.optionD.text = @"More info!";
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)buttonAPressed:(UIButton *)first sender:(id)sender {

    // Situation 1
    if (_sit == 0) {
        _sit = 1;
    }

    // Situation 2
     if (_sit == 1) {
        _sit = 2;
    }

    // Situation 3
     if (_sit == 2) {
        _sit = 3;
    }

    // Situation 4
     if (_sit == 3) {
        _sit = 4;
    }

    // Situation 5
     if (_sit == 4) {
        _sit = 6;
    }

    // Situation 6
     if (_sit == 5) {
        _sit = 2;
    }
}

- (IBAction)buttonBPressed:(UIButton *)first sender:(UIButton *)sender {

    // Situation 1
     if (_sit == 0) {
        _sit = 2;
    }

    // Situation 2
    if (_sit == 1) {
        _sit = 5;
    }

    // Situation 3
    if (_sit == 3) {
        _sit = 13;
    }

    // Situation 4
    if (_sit == 4) {
        _sit = 7;
    }

    // Situation 5
    if (_sit == 5) {
        _sit = 0;
    }
}

- (IBAction)buttonCPressed:(UIButton *)first sender:(UIButton *)sender {

    // Situation 1
    if (_sit == 0) {
        _sit = 8;
    }

    // Situation 2
    if (_sit == 1) {
        _sit = 0;
    }

    // Situation 3
    if (_sit == 3) {
        _sit = 9;
    }

    // Situation 4
    if (_sit == 4) {
        _sit = 10;
    }
}

- (IBAction)buttonDPressed:(UIButton *)first sender:(UIButton *)sender {

    // Situation 1
    if (_sit == 0) {
        _sit = 11;
    }

    // Situation 2
    if (_sit == 1) {
        _sit = 5;
    }

    // Situation 3
    if (_sit == 3) {
        _sit = 12;
    }
}
@end
```

Here's the newest crash logs:

```
 2014-08-07 05:45:18.007 Adventure Game[5942:60b] -[BKViewController aButtonPressed:]:   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8c80850
 2014-08-07 05:45:18.032 Adventure Game[5942:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception     'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[BKViewController aButtonPressed:]: unrecognized selector    sent to instance 0x8c80850'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x017ee1e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0156d8e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0188b243 -[NSObject(NSObject)      doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x017de50b ___forwarding___ + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x017de0ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0157f880 -[NSObject    performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
    6   UIKit                               0x0022f3b9 -[UIApplication   sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108
    7   UIKit                               0x0022f345 -[UIApplication   sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
    8   UIKit                               0x00330bd1 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
    9   UIKit                               0x00330fc6 -[UIControl  _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 577
     10  UIKit                               0x00330243 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] +   641
    11  UIKit                               0x0026eddd -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 852
    12  UIKit                               0x0026f9d1 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1117
    13  UIKit                               0x002415f2 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    14  UIKit                               0x0022b353 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11455
     15  CoreFoundation                      0x0177777f     __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
     16  CoreFoundation                      0x0177710b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
     17  CoreFoundation                      0x017941ae __CFRunLoopRun + 910
     18  CoreFoundation                      0x017939d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
     19  CoreFoundation                      0x017937eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
     20  GraphicsServices                    0x037e25ee GSEventRunModal + 192
     21  GraphicsServices                    0x037e242b GSEventRun + 104
     22  UIKit                               0x0022df9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
     23  Adventure Game                      0x00003e1d main + 141
     24  libdyld.dylib                       0x01e35701 start + 1
)
 libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: put code of `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` method

Comment: is there any message in console?

Comment: Nothing in console.  :(

Comment: You have an infinity loop in `while(_sit == 0)`. I got your point, whenever a button is pressed, the situation will change. However, it's probably blocking the main thread. Could you change it for if condition and try again?

Comment: Did you make any change to this method  `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

Comment: I tried changing the while to if.  When I ran it, it opened showing the error image you get on an iPhone when an app doesn't have an icon (It's white with a gray circle and X).  After a couple seconds, it closed out the app and returned to the home screen.

What do you mean by did I change the method Mohit Popat?  I inserted the method into the header file and it made no difference if that's what you mean.

Comment: :D After awhile of the black screen, the app finally opened.  I tried to press a button to test it, and the app crashed immediately though.  :(  It gave a report in main.m saying "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT"

Comment: what is crash message?

Comment: You should change these functions : - (IBAction)buttonAPressed:(UIButton *)first sender:(id)sender , they should have only once sender parameter. You can only add the second parameter as Event.

Comment: Reposting this with more info: After the crash, it opened main.m and highlighted the code:     return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil,       NSStringFromClass([BKAppDelegate class])); saying "Thread 1: signal SIGABR".  (Sorry if formatting is wrong.  Still trying to figure it out...)

Comment: I removed the first sender parameter (I added it in the beginning because it was giving an error, which couldn't actually affect the build, that was giving me OCD xD).  I ran the app, and simulator opened with it.  When I pressed a button again, it crashed saying the same thing.

Comment: Console started saying stuff:
    2014-08-07 05:32:51.010 Adventure Game[5866:60b] -[BKViewController      aButtonPressed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8c3b360
     2014-08-07 05:32:51.016 Adventure Game[5866:60b] *** Terminating app      due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-    [BKViewController aButtonPressed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance      0x8c3b360'
    *** First throw call stack:
There's a lot more, but it't too long to put in a comment.  I'll add it to the main post.

Answer (score 1):

```
2014-08-07 05:45:18.007 Adventure Game[5942:60b] -[BKViewController aButtonPressed:]:
```

Your crash report is showing BKViewController has reference to aButtonPressed but in  your code there is no button such. Check if you had created IBAction for the button with aButtonPressed if so remove it. Also reset your simulator once using iOS simulator > Reset content and setting option.

Comment: That worked!  Thanks so much!  Thanks to codeIgnitor and Timur Kuchkarov, as well as everyone else!  :D

Answer (score 0):

Your app crashes because you added button action named "aButtonPressed" and connected it in storyboard, but looks like then you renamed it to `buttonAPressed:(UIButton *)first sender:(id)sender` but didn't update it in storyboard(you should use refactor->rename for this, usually xcode renames selector in storyboard). So you try to invoke selector on target(controller) but controller doesn't know how to respond to it and the default behavior is to raise an exception.

@codeIgnitor mentioned the line you should pay attention is such cases.